# Can I change default foreign key for my Laravel Relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

I am currently working on a project that uses Laravel, but that was not using the relationships.

I set them a few months ago, but none of the tables id are set as `variable_id` but `id_variable`.

I quote Laravel doc.

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the parent model name.

In this case, the `Phone` model is automatically assumed to have a `user_id` foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the `hasOne` method.

So that's what I did everywhere, but I want to know if I can set the default id key to a model?
For the User model for example:

somthing like

```php
default_foreign_key : 'id_user'
```

So that when I write

```
return $this->hasOne(User::class);
```

it uses `id_user` instead of `user_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add foreign key as you wish:

```
$this->hasOne(User::class,'id_user');
```

You can create an abstract class extended from model and override this method inside of it:

```
public function getForeignKey()
{
    return Str::snake(class_basename($this)).'_'.$this->getKeyName();
}
```

and then extends your models from this custom model. (feel free for naming).
I think this should work for you.

for your requirement I think the codes inside method should be like this:

```
 return $this->getKeyName().'_'.Str::snake(class_basename($this));
```

Comment: I edited the answer please check it @Steyo

Comment: I'm gonna try this and validate your answer if it works. Thank you ;)

Comment: Please change the code inside of the method as you want it to be. This is default codes. I think it should be like this:    

return $this->getKeyName() .'_'.Str::snake(class_basename($this));

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has naming convention for relation/ db keys, but you can define custom keys, like it is described in [One To One
documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

You can set foreign key name:

```
$this->hasOne(Phone::class, 'foreign_key');
```

and even you can define key names on both sides:

```
$this->hasOne(Phone::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Comment: Like I said, that's what I did and it works. But I would like to know if there is a way to set the foreign_key as default in a model, so that when I use $this->hasOne(User::class) I don't need to put the foreign key anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can its also mentioned in the Laravel documentation

```
$this->hasOne(User::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Comment: Like I said, that's what I did and it works. But I would like to know if there is a way to set the foreign_key as default in a model, so that when I use $this->hasOne(User::class) I don't need to put the foreign key anymore.

Comment: @Steyo The foreign key is not proper to the model, it depends on the related model so it make sens to define it on the relation to that model. The solution you are looking for is to use the default naming of laravel.